# Can't send audio file with telegram bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I've got stuck trying to get my bot to send audio file and tried reading everything I can and for some reason still not working...

this is my code, its quite long so i've just included relevant parts:

```
import Constants as keys
from telegram.ext import *
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup,InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, CallbackQuery, Update
import time
import Responses as R
import song
import logging
import emoji
import random
import requests

def yes_command(update, context):
    time.sleep(5)
    update.message.reply_text("Let's test here, press play to listen.")
    time.sleep(3)
    update.message.reply_audio("press play", audio=open("C:/Users/0836/Documents/omsk/bot2/song/bootgong.mp3"))

def main():
    updater = Updater(keys.API_KEY, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start_command))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("play", play_command))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("no", no_command))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("yes", yes_command))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, handle_message))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.photo, photo_command))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
    
    
    main()
```

I'm really new to bots and python so not sure what i'm doing wrong, please help! I've seen stuff about uploading it to a telegram server but not sure how?

Comment: try to load the file first then add it to the reply audio function

Comment: where do i load it? sorry am very new

Comment: `f = open("demofile.txt", "r")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add `'rb'` in open

```
update.message.reply_audio(open("C:/Users/0836/Documents/omsk/bot2/song/bootgong.mp3", "rb"), title="press play")
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: TypeError: reply_audio() got multiple values for argument 'audio'

Comment: oh the first argument should be the file (this is a helper method)

Comment: see https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html?highlight=reply_audio#telegram.Message.reply_audio

Comment: lol also new to stackoverflow just realised how to do it :) thanks !